# 170k item array not being processed correctly

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js

I have a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f2cQ5/7/) (note: accesses a nearly 2k file via JSONP).  It has a small word list at load consisting of two and three letter words, which are loaded into an array.  It's then filtered using `Array.prototype.filter`.  This works.

Then my page starts downloading the Enable1 word list (used by most games featuring a word list).  At this point, my filter functions ends up with an empty array, instead of the expected 105 words.

I can confirm that, both before and after,

- my word list has the same starting word (`aa`) which should be displayed,
- the lists have 1091 and 172820 words respectively
- all words are lowercase, and have no surrounding spaces
- on load, the only filtering criteria is "has exactly two letters"
- there are no errors on the console
- there is a 100mb (25%) increase in the Fiddle's page's RAM usage, my system has 35% RAM remaining

Here's my code.

```
function VM() {  
    var self = this;

    self.characters = ko.observable(2);

    self.words = ko.observableArray(document.getElementById("words")
        .innerHTML.split(/\s+/g).slice(1, -1)
        .map(function (word) {
        return word.toLowerCase();
    }));        

    self.possible = ko.computed(function () {
        var letters = self.letters(),
            starters = self.startsWith(),
            enders = self.endsWith(),
            characters = self.characters();

        return self.words().filter(function (word) {
            return word.length === parseInt(characters);
        })
            .filter(function (word) {
            if (enders === "") return true;

            for (var i = enders.length; i >= 0; --i) {
                if (word.slice(-1) === enders[i]) return true;
            }

            return false;
        })/* other filtering code */;

    });
}

ko.applyBindings(app = new VM);

$.getJSON('http://anyorigin.com/get?url=https://scrabble-dictionary-search.googlecode.com/svn-history/r6/trunk/src/main/resources/enable1.txt&callback=?', function(data){
    app.words(data.contents.split("\n"));
    console.log(app.words().length);
});
```

What is causing this?  How can I get it to work the same as it does with the smaller list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is when you "split" the result of your ajax call. If you log the array that you obtain when you split the response, you will see things like that: "aa\r".

If you use:

```
app.words(data.contents.split("\r\n"));
```

Instead of:

```
app.words(data.contents.split("\n"));
```

That will be better.